# How to run a command multiple times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, agent-based-modeling

I am working on an agent-based model and I would like to run the following command 1,000 times:

```
model = MyModel()
for i in range(100):
    model.step()
```

I decided to use the while loop:

```
repetition = 0  
maxRepetition = 1000
while repetition <= maxRepetition: 
    model = MyModel()
    for i in range(100):
        model.step()    
    repetition += 1
```

Nonetheless, it takes this loop a huge amount of time to conclude (more than 1 hour). Could anyone please recommend me a more efficient procedure?

Comment: What this code intend to do ? Depends on that if the code inside a loop can be run concurently or not.

Comment: We dont know what `step()` does, but sure, running a function 100,000 times sequentally will be slow. You could instead start 1000 independent threads

Comment: ABMs often run on a grid, say 100x100 - that is you need to update 10,000 cells 100 times, 1000 times... this takes time! If your program is working, I suggest you post a request for help on codereview.stackexchange, this is probably a better place for this sort of questions.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the code above would likely be closed as off-topic because it is missing context, which happens all to often.

Comment: The "step( )" function makes the agents perform their respective functions for 1 cycle. There are 5 agents sequentially executing functions in the model. The code is really big, that's why I only put the last part, but I forgot to explain "step( )"

Comment: haha, you get your share of bad questions on CR too. Of course, I envisioned a great question, with all the relevant code and details, but I will keep your suggestion in mind @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ, because that was a silent, and ambitious assumption; thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `model.step()` doesn't require iterational execution than there are libraries like `threading`, `asyncio` and `multiprosessing` for use.

```
import multiprocessing

def run_model(n):
    model = MyModel()
    for i in range(100):
        model.step

with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(run_model, list(range(1000)))
```

source: https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/